# Toggling a button's state in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, button, radio-button, togglebutton, use-state

I have a button "Next" and I want it to be disabled initially, unless the user has selected the date. I also have 2 radio buttons like so:

[image]

I have the "One day" radio button selected by default. If I have that selected and the user has also selected the date, I want to enable the Next button. But if the user decides to move to the "Multiple days " radio button I want to disable the next button because over there the user hasn't selected a date yet. Once he has, the Next button gets enabled.

**Here is how I made my radio buttons:**

```
 <FormControl component="fieldset">
                        <FormLabel component="legend">You can choose to generate a one day or a multiple days
                            report.</FormLabel>
                        <RadioGroup
                            row
                            aria-label="position"
                            name="position"
                            defaultValue="one"
                            onChange={handleRadioChange}>

                            <FormControlLabel
                                value="one"
                                control={<Radio color="primary"/>}
                                label="One day"
                                labelPlacement="end"/>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                value="multiple"
                                control={<Radio color="primary"/>}
                                label="Multiple Days"
                                labelPlacement="end"/>

                        </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
```

**This is the function handleRadio Change: (fromDate,ToDate, OneDate are actually the values of the date)**

```
 const handleRadioChange = (event) => {
        setRadioValue(event.target.value);
        setHideOne((prev) => !prev);

        if(radioValue === 'one'){
            oneDate === null ? setNextButton(true) : setNextButton(false)

        }
        else if(radioValue === 'multiple'){
             (fromDate === null && toDate === null) ? setNextButton(true) : setNextButton(false)

        }


    }
```

With this code, when I select The One day date, the Next button gets enabled which is correct, but when I move to the Multiple Days radio button, it remains enabled. And when I switch back to One day it gets disabled.

### Edit

I've made the initial state to true i.e the button will be disabled initially:

```
    const [nextButton, setNextButton] = useState(true)
```

Here is the button :

```
<Button
                                            variant="contained"
                                            color="primary"
                                            onClick={() => handleNext(index)}
                                            className={classes.button}
                                            disabled={nextButton}
                                        >
```

Comment: What is the method `setNextButton`? What is the code behind `fromDate` and `toDate`? please elaborate

Comment: @yoni fromDate and toDate are just storing the values of the date, the user selected. Whereas, setNextButton sets the state of the Next button to either false or true i.e it decides whether the button display attribute should be false or true. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Why are you sure that `fromDate` and `oneDate` and `toDate` are `null` by default? I assume that the problem is there. You can check it with the browser's console with a proper breakpoint.

Comment: because I've set them to null initially just the way i did nextbutton state